# How to see what process is triggered with a PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, command-line, process, winget

currently, I am trying to get some silent install commands out of the winget cmdlet in order to deploy win32apps via intune. Most of the time I just run the powershell window without admin & when I use the below command (with adobe for example) it prompts for admin credentials and shows me the process i.e. "do you want to make following changes to your pc blabla AcroRdrDCx642200220191_MUI.exe /sAll /rs /rps /l /re"

Is there a different method to see what kind of process a cmdlet triggers? because some apps don´t need admin for their .exe´s and I can´t look up random silent install commands in the internet, neither use so called "tools" to determine them, because either they are expensive as hell or not reliable.

would be nice if someone can help me out here :)

```
winget install --exact --silent --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements "randomapp"
```

Comment: `winget` is _not_ a PowerShell cmdlet, it's an external application.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `winget install <package> --verbose-logs` you can open up the log file and see which switches were passed to the installer. The log file location is displayed via `winget --info`.